# Place of adjective Place in the sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order

> There is a long Neva River in Saint Petersburg.

Is it correct to put this adjective (long) this way?

Comment: It's fine to describe a river as 'long', but the way you put it sounds as though the whole length of the Neva were within the city! It would be better to say that it _passes through_ St. Petersburg.

Comment: Also the sentence could imply that there is, or might be, a _short_ Neva River in St Petersburg, which is probably nonsense (I've never been to Russia).